# Removing bold from header using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to remove bold from headers, and I am able to do this for `Heading 1` with this code:

```
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .Format = True
    .Style = "Heading 1"
    .Execute
    .Parent.Bold = False
End With
```

However this doesn't appear to work for other levels of Headers. To remove `Heading 4` I try:

```
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .Format = True
    .Style = "Heading 4"
    .Execute
    .Parent.Bold = False
End With
```

But it doesn't do anything. When I manually search for style=`Heading 4` using advanced `ctrl-f` everything is bolded.

Comment: Are you sure? I only have a Heading 1 and Heading 2 style, but this code works for both of those...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work without using the `.Find` method at all, you can directly interact with the `Style` objects, like so:

```
Dim s As Style
Set s = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 4")
s.Font.Bold = False
```